# McDonnell Douglas DC10 - scale model

Tags: safety, dc-10

I am building a scale model of a DC10. I need precise details of the external lighting arrangements. The red and green wingtip nav lights are obvious but I need the details of other beacons and their precise locations - red flashing dorsal and ventral and any white lights - flashing or steady.

I would be grateful for any help you can give.

Comment: Airport planning docs sometimes have this information, check here https://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/commercial/airports/acaps/dc10.pdf

I seem to recall an extensive website dedicated to the DC-10/KC-10 with a huge amount of technical detail.  Unfortunately, I can't find it at this time.

Comment: [This](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/98/32/29/98322953a864a55b426059a93bf7bdd2.jpg) might help

Answer (score 0):

There is some details in this online document. Not much details but as you should be able to fix the location fairly accurately.

I seem to remember the landing lights only swing out when activated and remain flush otherwise. When activated the lights will switch on and swing out so when you observe them as they deploy the beam will point sideways and swivel until they are pointing forwards.

https://dokumen.tips/documents/mcdonnell-douglas-dc-10-flight-crew-operating-manual.html?page=10